# Create scheduled clone of OS drive? - Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, backup, clone, ubuntu-server

I have a home-built NAS at home, where a single drive drives the OS and 4 drives a RAID 5 array.

The trouble is I don't want to risk harddrive failure on my single drive which holds the OS. That drive is 160 GB and I have another 160GB drive lying around and would love to have a complete clone of the OS drive, which in case the OS drive fails, I could just swap the other cloned drive in the same port and continue as nothing has happened.

I would like to schedule this backup to be done like once per week, and do it automatically.
The drive could be attached from an external drive or internal port. The main thing is I want a scheduled backup and have the ease to use the cloned drive as an easy restore drive.

How do I do this?
I have thought about different methods, like having the OS in a RAID 1 array, but I would most of all to have some sort of backup solution that does not require the cloned drive to work all the time.

What are the methods I can use to achieve this?
And what program/script should I look at?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Clonezilla Server? http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE/